# MySQL first day and last day of current and previous month from date (no timestamp)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I hope following query will give you the idea what I am looking for-

```
SELECT SUM(t1.hours) AS totalhours FROM
(
    SELECT (time_to_sec(timediff(time_out, time_in)) / 3600) AS hours FROM bb_work_log 
    WHERE user_id = 6 AND (working_date BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-31')
) AS t1
```

In my query, you can see the `working_date` which I given here manually. But, I would not like to do it manually. I would like to pick first day and last day of current month dynamically.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY`,which will subtract one month from now and by by adding 1 day in `LAST_DAY` of previous month will give you the first day of current month

```
SELECT SUM(t1.hours) AS totalhours FROM
(
    SELECT (time_to_sec(timediff(time_out, time_in)) / 3600) AS hours FROM bb_work_log 
    WHERE user_id = 6 
    AND (working_date BETWEEN LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
    AND LAST_DAY(NOW()))
) AS t1
```

> LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)  this will give you the last day of
>   previous month

### [First/Last day of Month Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/35217)

Comment: If I want to pick for last month

Comment: @Khan [*see demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/35218) for last day of previous month

Comment: Yeah, I got your point. Will help my question to other user? If help, please appreciate the question.

Answer (score 21):

**First day of Previous Month**

```
select last_day(curdate() - interval 2 month) + interval 1 day
```

**Last day of Previous Month**

```
select last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month)
```

**First day of Current Month**

```
select last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month) + interval 1 day
```

**Last day of Current Month**

```
select last_day(curdate())
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve it these ways ----

```
/* Current month*/
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()))-1 DAY),CONCAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()),' 23:59:59');

SELECT LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()))-1 DAY ,CONCAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()),' 23:59:59');

/* previous month*/
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00'),DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- first day of previous month
set @start_date = date_format(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01');
-- last day of previous month
set @end_date = date_format(NOW() , '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 day;
select @start_date ,@end_date ;
--  first day of current month
set @start_date = date_format(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01');
-- last dat of current month
set @end_date = date_format(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 day;
select @start_date ,@end_date ;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you add some explanation how this solves the problem?